# Assigned A record for Subdomain in Cloud DNS to Compute Engine VM instance but not propagated/resolved yet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-compute-engine, subdomain, google-cloud-dns

I've assigned an A record in Cloud DNS to one of my Compute Engine VM instances, but it's not being resolved for 12 hours.

Should I wait longer (I mean, is it OK that it's not propagated yet, after 12 hours), or did I mis-configured something in Cloud DNS panel?

Main/Parent domain (without subdomain) is assigned to another Compute Engine VM instance and it's working fine, and being resolved (tested with `nslookup`)

But as showing in screenshot, A record of Subdomain is not being propagated, after 12 hours.

Also, when I try to reach to subdomain in Chrome, I get an `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error. But when I try to reach VM Instance Ephemeral (Static) IP address, it works fine on 80 (HTTP).

---

[image: Cloud DNS configuration]

---

[image: Chrome ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error]

---

[image: nslookup Non-existent domain result]

---

[image: whatsmydns.net test result]

Comment: You are creating resource records at the wrong DNS servers. The authoritative servers for your domain are `ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com` ... A good tool to use to immediately test your DNS changes is https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ Login to the Registrar for your domain and make sure the correct DNS servers are declared.